# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (POST parameters exceeds the maximum. (CF 2018 release)

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

How to fix Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (POST parameters exceeds the maximum. (CF 2018 release)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the *Request Size Limits Maximum number of POST request parameters* setting. The default is 100. I changed it to 1000 and then 9000. I guess it needed to be higher number.

[image: Administrator Parameter]

Comment: This limit is protection against a HashDos attack, You can find more info here: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/808.cfm Yes you can increase this value, but consider why you're posting so much data at once and what could you do differently to avoid exposing your application to this attack.